# iOS : Timezone Issue on Local timezone of iPhone device

Tags: ios, datetime, timezone, nsdateformatter

I have been working on an application that takes dates from server in a certain format as given below.

> **"2015-02-03 00:00:00"**

I want to show them with different UI format using **NSDateFormatter**
but as i change the timezone it show previous day or sometimes next day as i changing timezone. One important thing that server side date can be in any of timezone. So, we don't know what kind of timezone date has.
I need help to show this to the date as it is on server not change due to local timezone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to parse it as if it were UTC - making it *always* valid, and without ever needing DST adjustments - and then format it in UTC as well. In other words, set the time zone of both the formatter and parser to UTC. For types which *need* a time zone, that's the simplest way of faking "There isn't a time zone here, just treat it all as local to an unspecified time zone."

Comment: thanks for your precious time.
i am new bee and got a little confuse will tell me a little kind of code

Comment: Well we haven't got any of your *current* code to work with, so it would be hard to say what do to. But basically you should have two `NSDateFormatter` objects - one for parsing, one for formatting, right? Set the time zone in both to UTC.